# Answers and Reputation headers are not aligned

Tags: bug, design

Tabs (Answers and Reputation) are not aligned with auto-height property under the Summary tab of user Activity.

[image]

Comment: Can reproduce in Firefox 57.0.3 on Debian GNU/Linux, where the difference on my system is about 4.3667 pixels.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if it is [status-bydesign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), however. Maybe the orange line under *votes/activity/newest* can be moved closer to the text?

Comment: Can reproduce on Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I swear this has been mentioned before. In any case, it's due to the padding on the `.subtabs a, .filter a { ... }` css ("votes activity newest" links). Any amount greater than 6 pixels will nudge the header down.

Comment: My OCD just kicked in :/

Comment: Same for "Answers" and "Tags" in the meta profile.