# Fix the headers in the user account dashboard

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

The headers are ever-so misaligned depending on if there's a submenu nested in them:

[image]

Can we get them so that they line up?

[image]

Comment: [Same cause as this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361465/answers-and-reputation-headers-are-not-aligned)